# Passing source and binaries directories to Sonar

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I am setting up Sonar through Jenkins Sonar plugin and I have a couple of questions about the way Sonar interprets the directories I give it.

1. `sources=srcDir1,srcDir2` : from what I understand this is where I pass source dir of my project. My project is actually a multiproject with many source dirs inside. Is it okay to give Sonar the root path to the project and Sonar will know to go deep and find each projects `.java` files ? Or do I have to give it each one of the source dirs ? Also if I have `src/com/mycompany/myproj/...` package structure do I have to give it the end path, or the src path is sufficient ?
2. `binaries=binDir` : Here I should give Sonar the path to the compiled `.class` code or the packed `.jar / .war / .ear` files so Findbugs will work. Same question here: I don't have a central place with all the compiled classes, so do I have to specify each one of the paths ?

Comment: You appear to be analysing Java and it seems obvious you're not using Maven, but... I can't tell if you're using the Sonar ANT task... If you're using the Java runner I would have to ask why? Are you building the code using something other than ANT or Maven?

Comment: I'm using Jenkins Sonar plugin, but my question is more general, on how Sonar interprets the properties passed to it

Comment: @Micheal The Jenkins plugin is really designed to support Maven. If you're using ANT you are best advised to integrate the ANT task into your build logic so that it can take advantage of any paths you've created listing the jars your code depends on (Needed by Findbugs). As for how the properties are used, this is described in the doc link I've given below. You need to read this because support for multi-module builds is an added complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sonar ANT task contains a section on how to configure Sonar to analysis a multi-module build:

- http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Ant+Task